# How to Convert webview to Image

Tags: image, webview, xamarin.forms

I am Using Xamarin form. 
I want to convert **Webview** to byte[] for printing functionality.
my code is below

```
// Generate the HTML
var htmlString = printTemplate.GenerateString();

// Create a source for the web view
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
htmlSource.Html = htmlString;

// Create and populate the Xamarin.Forms.WebView
var browser = new WebView();
browser.Source = htmlSource;

var printService = DependencyService.Get<IPrintService>();
printService.Print({{I WANT byte[] /Image here}});
```

Comment: If you need a printing functionality, this may help you: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/23158/#Comment_23158

Comment: @DennisSchröer
'Xamarin.Forms.WebView' does not contain a definition for `MainFrame' and no extension method `MainFrame' of type `Xamarin.Forms.WebView' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?